# Connecting Dell 1660w printer to wifi in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, printing

Can anybody help to connect my Dell 1660w colour laserprinter to Wifi with Ubuntu 14.04?
I tried a lot of solutions that I found in askubuntu but the only result, when printing a testpage was the message: idle waiting for printer to be ready.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what steps did you take to set up the printer, what the IP address is, what the IP address of the machine is, ...  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Answer (score 0):

Posting for posterity's sake. I was able to print to my Dell 1660w (which is networked) by installing the following package:

`sudo apt-get install libcupsimage2:i386`

Downloaded the DEB driver for the Xerox Phaser 6000B: http://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-6000/downloads/engb.html?operatingSystem=linux

Installed the Dell 1660W using the above driver by specifying Phaser 6000B in CUPS. It worked!

Side note: I attempted to use dcoffin's HBPL driver (http://cybercom.net/~dcoffin/hbpl/) but had no success. Was able to compile, install, and specify the printer driver in CUPS but all print jobs would report completed immediately with nothing actually printing.